# Choosing ARFIMA parameters for fitting (R)

Tags: r, time-series, arfima

I have very broad question, because I think I'm missing something not too complicated. 
I'm trying to fit the suitable ARFIMA model for the data.
I used fdGPH to estimate fractional differencing parameter. How to estimate afterwards order parameters for the model - p and q? Command "arfima(data,fixed = list(frac = 0.4))" gives only log-likelihood and $\sigma^2.$
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Questions about how to use R would be better on a more programming oriented site like R-help or StackOverflow but they would both need some more detail to give a full answer.

Comment: This seems to be a straightforward question about [model selection for ARFIMA](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=model+selection+for+ARFIMA&t=ffsb&ia=web) models. The R aspect seems of lesser importance. Voting to leave open.

Comment: Although this could be reformulated as a software-neutral model selection question, at present it seems to be really just about R code. It also seems like the corresponding statistical question would be too broad. I'm voting to close, but am open to retracting that vote or reopening this thread if adequately improved.